# Creacion de .zip con php

Tags: php, zip

Estoy tratando de crear una carpeta comprimida con php en estos momentos agrega un solo archivo pero la idea es que sea dinámico.

```
function crear_zip($id_paciente){
    $files = array( 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bitnami.txt' );
    $zipname = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\zipped_file.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE); 
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();
}
```

El problema es que en el .zip me pone es una copia de la ruta q le di y no el archivo intente dandole solo el nombre del archivo pero al parecer no lo encuentra y no me crea el .zip.. ¿alguna idea?.. Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué te devuelve en la variable `$file`?

Comment: me devuelve el mismo C:\xampp\htdocs\bitnami.txt

Comment: y en los ejemplos que encuentro todos hacen el index y tienen los archivos a comprimir en la misma carpeta pero yo necesito buscarlos de diferentes partes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que no le pasas el segundo parámetro a la función `$zip->addFile`, y por tanto asume el mismo nombre de archivo (incluyendo la ruta).

De acuerdo a [la documentación](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfile.php): (traducción libre mía)

> bool ZipArchive::**addFile** ( string **$filename** [, string **$localname** ] )
>
> **filename**
>   La ruta al archivo que se añade.
>
> **localname**
>   El nombre local dentro del fichero ZIP.

Esto significa que el primer parámetro es la ruta al archivo *real* que deseas añadir en el sistema de archivos del servidor, mientras que el segundo es la ruta y nombre de archivo que este tendrá dentro del archivo comprimido ZIP.

Debes entonces pasar el segundo parámetro, y en este utilizar solamente el nombre del archivo (para lo que puedes valerte de la función [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.basename.php). Algo similar a:

```
function crear_zip($id_paciente){
    $files = array( 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bitnami.txt' );
    $zipname = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\zipped_file.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE); 
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      $localfile = basename($file);
      $zip->addFile($file, $localfile);
    }
    $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: Si! muchisimas gracias.. eso era!.. una pregunta estoy tratando de buscar estos archivos del servidor en estos momentos estoy en el local.. y le paso la ruta http://localhost/hc_prod/public/archivo_pacientes/639/SW601805.pdf si abro esta url me trae el pdf pero el no me crea el .zip.. alguna idea?

Comment: @Laura, debes pasar la ruta en el sistema de archivos local, no una url.  Es decir, si estás en windows, `c:\ruta\de\la\carpeta\archivo.pdf` y si estás en *nix algo como `/var/local/archivo.pdf`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias :) ya probé y si.. es eso..